# why is junit not not visible at all in my eclipse java compiler

Tags: java

I am relatively new in java programming specifically with eclipse environment. I am trying to use junit and tried the following

```
import org.junit.*;
```

however this is not working because junit is not part of the org package. nevertheless junit is installed on my computer. please could anyone tell me what could be wrong. from the java tutorials I have read so far, nothing is wrong with my code

Answer (score 2):

The `JUnit` JAR file is not included in the project build path.

Include the JAR file in project classpath for the current `Eclipse` project. Ensure the file is visible from the `Package Explorer` View. Then right click on the JAR file and select

```
Build Path > Add to Build Path
```

Alternatively, if you're using Maven, you can simply add the `JUnit` dependency your project's `POM.XML` file

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.11</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: thank you very much.. is there a way of including it in the jre system library instead of referrence

Comment: You could use `Preferences > Java > User Libraries > Import`. Bear in mind that this will restrict all the Eclipse project to use the same version of `JUnit` so using a _per-project_ include (as above) is preferable. Have a look at using [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/). It makes this type of work very easy.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the junit library to the classpath of your project.

In `Eclipse` you can do it like this:

right click on your project then go to

```
Build path > Configure Build path...
```

switch to the `Libraries` tab then click `add Library`. Choose `JUnit` and hit `next`, choose witch version you want, 3 or 4 (I recommend 4). Hit `finish` then hit `OK`.

That's it.

Answer (score 1):

Following onfrom reimus,  For my version of eclipse (other version may differ):

- Try right clicking on the package
- Select build path
- Select add libraries
- Select JUnit
- etc

You should then be able to use JUnit